# List of common cross-browser errors to look out for

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm aware of "new" css3 elementslike boxshadow, textshadow:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
```

Despite these, are there some common pitfalls our gotchas (html5, css3 or javascript related) you know of or have encountered?
Obviously there is **no way around testing** pages across the browsers but to avoid making some of these mistakes in the first place it would be nice if you could share your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to see most of the cross browser issues you can visit [here](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/15-techniques-and-tools-for-cross-browser-css-coding). This blog has good information about the things we need to take care of for a cross browser solution.